# How to bring back shell output buffer?

Tags: vim

after running a shell session in vim (e.g. `! ls`) and closing it (pressing `ENTER`), how do I bring back that content without running the command again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enter

```
:shell
```

This will put you into back into the shell session. You will have to exit this shell to return to vim again. Not sure of another way to view without doing this. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

The command, `$ ls`, was executed in the host shell, so you can suspend Vim with `<C-z>`, take a look, and then come back to Vim with `$ fg`.

Comment: thanks @romainl, both questions should be "The accepted one"

Comment: Hmm, no, not really. The two other answers solve your problem implicitly, via side effects, while mine does that explicitly. But that's your question so you do what you want.

Comment: both are by side effect and highly dependent on the environment. neither work with `gvim`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler than the previous answers, run `:!`